# Must issue STARTTLS error for sending email in vbscript

Tags: email, vbscript

I try to write a vbscript to send an email with some attachment file to another email. But when I try to execute the script in the window cmd, it's show me error message "The server reject the sender.The server response was 530 5.7.0. Must issue STARTLS"

I try change the port to 465 or 587 for the Google SMTP port/encryption. But it's also not working

Below is my vbscript :

```
Set email = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
email.Subject = "Test Email"
email.From = "kai7@gmail.com"
email.To = "kol@gmail.com"
email.TextBody = "Message Text."
email.AddAttachment "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Handover\v.txt"
email.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
email.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
email.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
email.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
email.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "username"
email.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "password"
email.Configuration.Fields.Update
email.Send
set email = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but trying to send to smtp.office365.com via port 587. What solved for me was changing the port to 25:

```
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2     objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
```

You are missing a field.

Check your inbox on the account you are using. Google is blocking you due a signin from a new program. **Click link in email from google**.

This is my full script with user/password blanked. Make sure from line is correct for your account.

Run this in a command prompt to you don't have to click ok 20 times,

```
cscript //nologo script.vbs
```

Script.vbs

```
On Error Resume next
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "dc@gmail.com"

emailObj.To       = "dc@gmail.com"

emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

For each f in emailConfig.Fields
    wscript.echo f.name & " " & f
Next

msgbox emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") 


emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "Dc"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "MyPassword"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

wscript.echo err.description

For each f in emailConfig.Fields
    wscript.echo f.name & " " & f
Next



If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "Done"
```

Comment: I get a message after I insert the missing portion, the error message show me the transport fail to connect to the server

Comment: when I execute this command in my window cmd, it's show me the line 18 has problem which is email.send syntax, this test script is running in my local pc

Comment: I didn't receive any link from google, any idea ? is it the script has problem or the smtp setting ? I checked the spam mail also didn't have the email

Comment: Check your sent mail and outbox in Mail in windows 10 as it uses the mail app to send mail.

Comment: I try to use the script provided by you, it show me error " the message cant send to smtp server " Refer to the link for the print screen I get from my window cmd  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZFpvcsafZtb1I2ZlBVbExOSlE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Until you tell google to allow it google will refuse it. This isn't a programming problem. Your issue is with your mail server.

Comment: any idea on how to tell google to allow it? I am a bit new to smtp

Comment: I click the link in the email.