# How to send pdf file via mail in command line after save it as pdf file

Tags: cmd, oraclereports

I am using Command Line that runs the oracle report 6i and save it as pdf and then send it by mail.
 actually, the part to run a report and save it as pdf is working fine

```
 rwrun REPORT=C:\reports\Rprtgroupleft.rdf DESTYPE=FILE DESNAME=c:\myreports\Rprtgroupleft.pdf DESFORMAT=pdf userid=scott/tiger@orcl
```

but now I need to add email in the same command line to send the pdf file but it is not working

```
 rwrun report=C:\reports\Rprtgroupleft.rdf userid=scott/tiger@orcl desformat=pdf DESTYPE=mail DESNAME="rere_ddd@hotmil.com"  replyto="rere_ddd@hotmil.com" from="rere_ddd@hotmil.com"
```

am not getting anything in my mail

Comment: See my earlier answer here. Note other persons problems are google specific.

Comment: @Noodles I can't see ur earlier answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545597/must-issue-starttls-error-for-sending-email-in-vbscript is the link I left out.

Comment: @Noodles there are no other ways without using Script.vbs ??

Comment: Not built in to windows.